# Docker icon system tray in ubuntu 16.04 Unity

Tags: ubuntu, docker, icons, ubuntu-16.04, system-tray

I'm looking for a Docker system tray icon which can show the running docker containers in the Unity GUI.

If I want to see my current running containers i have to use on the CLI "docker ps". But i do like to enable/disable and the see them within a system tray icon.

Unfortunately i was not able to found something similar online already. Is there any project, repo or tool availble that support this?

Having up around 60 docker containers for multiple services, a nice GUI overview would be a nice welcome.

Comment: what is this  docker - System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications ? from running apt-cache search docker

Comment: the docker package that's listed on [Debian docker](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/docker) is unrelated to Docker containers; it's an older, generic package to dock applications in a window manager. Fooled me too!

Answer (score 6):

The [Unity Docker indicator](https://github.com/yktoo/indicator-docker) might be what you are looking for.

But if you are looking for a general GUI then [kitematic](https://github.com/docker/kitematic), [dockstation](https://dockstation.io/), [Simple Docker UI](https://github.com/felixgborrego/simple-docker-ui) or [dockeron](https://github.com/dockeron/dockeron) might be something for you.

There is also a shell extension for recent Gnome versions called [gnome-shell-extension-docker](https://github.com/gpouilloux/gnome-shell-extension-docker) and if the other solutions don't fit you could also [open an issue](https://github.com/Toinane/container-ps/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc) for Linux support on [container-ps](https://github.com/Toinane/container-ps).